# how to return data instance of output class in api-platform's dto

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

From the document of api-platform's dto.It tell me to create a output class and a datatransformer 
when I use a output attribute for operation,it can not response instance of output class,what's wrong of it?

transformer is like this:

```php
final class RegistrationOutputTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
...
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function transform($data, string $to, array $context = [])
    {
        $content = $this->authenticationSuccessHandler->handleAuthenticationSuccess($data)->getContent();
        $output = $this->serializer->deserialize($content,AuthenticatedOutput::class,'json');
//        dump($output instanceof AuthenticatedOutput); // this is true
        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsTransformation($data, string $to, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return AuthenticatedOutput::class === $to && $data instanceof User;
    }
}
```

and entity

```
 *         "registration_by_mail"={
 *             "method"="POST",
 *             "path"="/users/register/mail",
 *             "input"=RegistrationMailUserInput::class,
 *             "output"=AuthenticatedOutput::class
 *         },
```

and output class

```php
final class AuthenticatedOutput
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $user_id;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $token_type;
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $expires_in;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $refresh_token;
    /**
     * @return int
     */

    public function getUserId(): int
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $user_id
     */
    public function setUserId(int $user_id): void
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }
...
```

the result of output

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http:\/\/phpna.local\/api\/docs.jsonld#",
    "hydra": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/ns\/hydra\/core#",
    "userId": "AuthenticatedOutput\/userId",
    "tokenType": "AuthenticatedOutput\/tokenType",
    "expiresIn": "AuthenticatedOutput\/expiresIn",
    "refreshToken": "AuthenticatedOutput\/refreshToken"
  },
  "@type": "User",
  "@id": "\/api\/users\/35"
}
```

I just want it output the instance of output class,what's error of my code？

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is a serialization problem, try using Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups annotations for the fields of your DTO class, as shown in the example below.

```
final class AuthenticatedOutput{
    /**
     * @Groups({"some_group_name"})
     * @var int
     */
    private $user_id;

    /**
     * @Groups({"some_group_name"})
     * @var string
     */
    private $token_type;

    /**
     * @Groups({"some_group_name"})
     * @var int
     */
    private $expires_in;

    /**
     * @Groups({"some_group_name"})
     * @var string
     */
    private $refresh_token;
...
```

Also, you can see the API platform DTO tests as an example [API Platform RecoverPasswordOutput](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/c80d4934ead61ffd4d5e08f3d86c79fa6fb75ce0/tests/Fixtures/TestBundle/Dto/RecoverPasswordOutput.php)

Answer (score 0):

Did you registered your `RegistrationOutputTransformer` class in `api/config/services.yaml`

eg.

```
# api/config/services.yaml
services:
    # ...
    'App\DataTransformer\RegistrationOutputTransformer': ~
        # Uncomment only if autoconfiguration is disabled
        #tags: [ 'api_platform.data_transformer' ]
```